# Computing Probability of an rBST

Tags: algorithm, math, random, probability, binary-search-tree

Hi all lets say we will insert A,B,C in an rBST(Binary Search Tree) random order, there would be 5 outcomes

```
 B   
A C 

A
  B
    C

   C
 B
A

  C
A
 B

A
  C
 B
```

a)What would be the probability of getting these trees?
b)What would be the probability if we added a "D" and it looked like this:

```
A
 B 
  C 
   D
```

Worst case probability? Thanks for your time!

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean by "worst case", so you're going to have to define what you mean by that term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to notice is that you have 3 elements initially.

You can thing of constructing BST as a recursive process. Firstly, you select the root and then recursively you construct the left and the right subtree - both of them are determined by the root.

If you have `n` items, the probability that you select one of them as a root of the tree is clearly `1/n` (I assume that random means uniformly random and independently of previous choices).

Of course, if you have 1 element or 0 elements there are only one tree possible, so the probability of constructing that tree is equal to `1`.

**Case 1:**

```
 B   
A C 

Pr = Pr(select B as a root of a whole tree) 
     * Pr(tree consisting of 1 element because only A is less than B) 
     * Pr(tree consisting of 1 element because only C is greater than B) 
   = 1/3 * 1 * 1 = 1/3
```

**Case 2:**

```
A
  B
    C

Pr = Pr(select A as a root of a whole tree) 
     * Pr(tree of 0 elements because none of elements is less than A)
     * Pr(select B as a root of tree of elements greater than A) 
     * Pr(tree of 0 elements because none of remaining elements is less than B)
     * Pr(tree of 1 element because C is greater than B) 
   = 1/3 * 1 * 1/2 * 1 * 1 = 1/6
```

**Cases 3, 4, 5:**

Constructing any of these trees is analogous to the **Case 2** because they share the same structure - you can compute the probabilities and check it.

**Summary**

Of course every possible BST on 3 elements is listed above, so the probability of these trees should sum up to 1, let's check it:

```
Pr(Case 1) + 4 * Pr(Case 2) = 1/3 + 4 * 1/6 = 1/3 + 4/6 = 1
```

You can figure out the answer to your second question examining the above method.